# Computer Fraud Related

Tags: united-states, fraud, gift-card

On 27th of May at around 1:30 P.M. (EST) I tried to order a small toy Online from Walmart.  I thought I dialed Walmart Online order 800 number.  The person who came to help me, conned me and took over my computer.  He told me don't move the cursor and while helping me to order the toy I was planning to buy, he swiftly ordered four $ 50 gift cards of Target and one $ 100 gift card of Amazon (total $ 300).  Since it was done from my computer, the credit card company cannot help me.  Walmart says, its workers cannot take over customer's computer.

My question is, would Target and Amazon have any record of who used those gift cards?  My belief is, the fraudster was so brazen (and I was so gullible) that he must not have taken any precaution to cover his crime.

Comment: The fraudster will almost certainly resell the gift cards.  The person who eventually uses them to buy something will probably be someone who's completely innocent, so finding them won't really help much.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that he moved and clicked your mouse through your phone line. And typed in his address.

Comment: Do you at least have the phone number that you mistakenly dialed? Perhaps stored on your landline phone  in the "recently dialed" list or maybe more permanently on your cellphone?

Comment: Where did you get the bad phone number?

Comment: Most credit cards now allow you to dispute charges that you did not authorize. So I would look at what benefits come with your credit card and give them a call if that's a benefit on your credit card.

Comment: I assume he remote desktopped into Pop's computer.

Comment: @aganju I'd guess the poster left out details. Probably fraudster told him to go to a certain website, do X, Y, and Z which resulted in downloading malicious software, etc.

Comment: Most companies require you to re-enter stored credit card numbers if you try to ship anything to a previously unknown address. Did you enter those numbers? Also your order records will tell you where those gift cards were shipped to. That should allow you to inform the police.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that "it was done from [your] computer" shouldn't mean that the credit card company can't help you. Did you call the credit card company and they told you that, or are you just assuming this or someone else told you this? If someone at the credit card company said that, ask to speak to their manager. I'm not an expert on credit card law by any means, but I would be very surprised if there was any rule that said that you are liable just because the fraud was done using your own computer. Lots of frauds are done by tricking people into going to a scam web site.

The key is to promptly contact the credit card company and report the fraud. If you report it within 2 days, your liability should be limited to $50. If you wait more than two days, it's $500.

If you call the credit card company and they sound unhelpful, I'd send them a certified letter -- in addition to calling -- so you have proof you notified them.

https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0213-lost-or-stolen-credit-atm-and-debit-cards